# IFs coming back false

Tags: javascript

Why are the if's on lines 28 and 39 (`if( clas == 1)` and `if( clas ==2 )` of this javascript always coming back false? If I replace the second with else. It gets executed every time. I have tried both `==` and `===` I have also tried putting the 1 and 2 as strings and both with and without the `clas = parseInt(cla)`

```
// JavaScript Document
var seat = new Array()
var fclass
var econ
var flight
var totseats

function init( seats, firclass, econo, flightnum )
{
    seat[0] = 'crew'
    fclass = firclass
    econ = econo
    flight = flightnum
    totseats = seats
    for( var count = 1; count <= seats; count++ )
    {
        seat[count] = 0;
    };
};

function reservation()
{
    var cla = document.getElementById('class').value;
    var name = document.getElementById('first').value;
    name += ' ';
    name += document.getElementById('last').value;
    clas = parseInt(cla)
    if( clas == 1 )
    {
        for( var seatnum = 1; seatnum < econ; seatnum++)
        {
            if( seat[seatnum] == 0 )
            {
                seat[seatnum] = name
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if( clas == 2 )
    {
        for( var seatnum = econ; seatnum < totseats; seatnum++)
        {
            if( seat[seatnum] == 0 )
            {
                seat[seatnum] = name
                break;
            }
        }
    };
    pticket( name, seatnum );
};

function pticket( name, seatnum )
{
    document.getElementById('tname').innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById('flight').innerHTML = 'Flight: ' + flight;
    document.getElementById('seat').innerHTML = seatnum;
    if( seatnum < econ )
    {
        document.getElementById('class').innerHTML = 'First Class';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('class').innerHTML = 'Economy';
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FB26t/1/
p.s. the jsfiddle doesn't run the script at all but it does run properly as an actual webpage

Comment: What value are they showing then you do a `console.log()`?

Comment: it looks like none but I'm not sure

Comment: and now I know why. I put the wrong element ID in

Comment: Which ifs, I'm not counting line # ... are you talking about `var cla =` but then `clas = parseInt(cla)` but clas is never set up yet you check it with an if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element with `id` *class* is not your `<select>`. That's why. Your class `<select>` element has `id` *select*.

Also you should specify the `radix` parameter to the `parseInt` function, because the default is not *10* in all browsers.

```
//and do not forget the var statement if you want a local variable
var clas = parseInt(cla, 10);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FB26t/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I had put `document.getElementById('class').value` but the corresponding element was actually `document.getElementById('select')`